# FormsAuthentication for HTML Pages in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Imagine we have 3 web pages, and two of these Name are Main.aspx (default url) & Login.aspx (login url),
The third One is index.html.
When I Want to see index.html it has no Login Page,
What Should I do to protect this page with Forms Authentication ?

How to Add the .html and other non-.NET extensions to the valid list of extensions to hand to the .NET engine ?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="MainPage.aspx" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: you can put this index.html out from master page & perform some logic on redirection

Comment: Require the third page to have no [Authorize] annotation, while Main does have that? Most tutorials feature a similar setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put html page in a folder and add new web.config to that folder with deny access to anonymous user in newly created web.config setting.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```